# SSDT 2017 deploy custom component error: couldn't be added to the Data Flow Task

Tags: ssis

I am trying to develop custom component in SSIS (SSDT 2017, doing the exercise in Microsoft 70-463 training kit Chapter 19 Lesson 3) and got the error when dragging the component to Data Flow Task:

---

The component could not be added to the Data Flow task.
Could not initialize the component. There is a potential problem in the ProvideComponentProperties method.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> Error at Data Flow Task [Calculate Checksum [80]]:
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.get_ComponentMetaData()'.
>   at Microsoft.TK463.CalculateCheckSum.ProvideComponentProperties()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProvideComponentProperties(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
>   wrapper)

---

Method not found:

> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.get_ComponentMetaData()'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

---

this is the script I used to deploy the Assembly:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /u TK463.CalculateCheckSum

copy "C:\TK463\Chp19\TK463Chp19\TK463.CalculateCheckSum\bin\Release\TK463.CalculateCheckSum.dll" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL erver\140\DTS\PipelineComponents"

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\PipelineComponents\TK463.CalculateCheckSum.dll"
```

I am not sure about the version of gacutil(v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools) I use and the route I copy DLL to (140\DTS\PipelineComponents), someone could explain about these two?

I also tried to change the value to False, but still got the error.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</Reference>
```

Is there anything to do about the building platform(x86, x64 or msil)?
Gave up after struggling for several hours, really need help.
thanks a lot.

PS: here is the `ProvideComponentProperties()`

```
public override void ProvideComponentProperties()
    {
        base.ProvideComponentProperties();

        // Create component properties.
        this.CreateCustomProperties();

        // Create Synchronous Output
        IDTSOutput100 output = ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection[0];
        output.SynchronousInputID = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[0].ID;

        // Create built-in output columns.
        this.CreateOutputColumns(ref output);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide code of `ProvideComponentProperties` method from your custom component.

Comment: @Ferdipux added the method in the question. Thanks.

Comment: what version of SQL/SSIS are you using? 2017 or 2016? Path `140\DTS\PipelineComponents` is for 2017 components, but versions of `<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap, Version=13.0.0.0` are for 2016. Some kind of mixture. 2017 has DLL versions 14.0.0.0.

Comment: @Ferdipux SQL 2016 Enterprise, SSDT 2017. I tried the path 130\DTS\PipelineComponents, the component didn't show in the SSDT toolbox, then changed to 140\DTS

Answer (score 1):

After bumping this problem again - I have found a solution to it.
Custom component needs references to the following DLLS - *Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSPipelineWrap, Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Microsoft.SQLServer.PipelineHost*.
All these DLL references have to be configured with **Embed Interop Types = False**. By default, VS adds some of them with this property set to **True**, which is the cause of the error.